# mysql, ordering of umlauts

Tags: mysql

I got a little problem with order in mysql (version 5, debian).

table and db-charset: latin1, column is varchar

I have a table that gives my an interesting ordering.

German Umlauts (Ä,Ö,Ü) are between A and B.
Thats also if I use differend collations after the order-clause.

Would understand if Ä would be after A and before B and Ö would be after O and before P ...
or all Umlauts after Z.

But not all Umlauts after A and before B.

any ideas?? thanks!

br,chris

Answer (score 1):

Results should be ordered by the collation of the table.  Note that collation and character set are independent characteristics.

To get the ordering you want, you can specify a collation in an ORDER BY clause: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html or change the collation in the table itsef.

Comment: yes. as I said, I tried collations. but without result. 
and what collation would any umlaut between A and B??

Comment: please se
example: 
Alarmanlagen                            
| Öhh                                           
| Übbb                                
| Überführungen                     
| ääsä                               
| Badsanierungen                 
| bbbb                                               | 
| Bestattungen                                       | 
| Biomasse-Heizungen                                
| Englisch 1                                
| Englisch 2                               
| Englischkurse 
| Erdwärmeheizungen    
| Fahrschule

Comment: If you do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘collation%’` from the MySQL command prompt, what shows up?